can I do android development to target an sdk older than that required by google play
I am hoping to develop apps for sdk older that that required for google play.
Is that possible and if so what IDE can I use.

In Android Studio in the gradle module script file look for the line that contains minSdk and set its value to the minimum you wish to support. This will instruct the gradle process to build your solution so it can support that Sdk.
